Java not recognized in Python venv on Windows 11
I'm trying to use the tabula-py library in a Python virtual environment on Windows 11. Java is installed on my system, and java -version works outside the venv. However, inside the venv, I get 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
Here are the steps I've tried so far:

Verified Java installation and set JAVA_HOME and PATH in system environment variables.
Edited activate.bat to include:

set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"

Despite these attempts, Java is still not recognized within the virtual environment. How can I ensure Java is available in the venv?
I'm using Pycharm as my IDE, if that helps.
Any help would be appreciated!

Inside the venv, if you echo $PATH, does it contain the java directory?

PyCharm Java support is very limited.I think IntellJ IDEA will be of great use to you. If you still wanna use check the coorect path in env using os.getenv('PATH') in Python1. This should return the Java library path..

To be clear - your goal is to start java processes from within the Python program using subprocess.call or something similar? Or else why exactly is this a problem?
